# Query for all matching IDs across multiple documents in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, filter, nosql

I'm creating an app that has a filtering utility. The structure of my FirestoreDB currently has a document for each filter category, and each of these documents contains a list of "things" for which that filter applies. Because more than one filter may apply to a specific "thing", copies of that "thing" may appear in multiple filter documents.

### Database Basic Structure:

*filters* (collection)
**--filterA** (doc)
----thing1
------id
----thing2
------id
**--filterB** (doc)
----thing2
------id
----thing3
------id
**--filterC** (doc)
----thing1
------id
----thing3
------id

[image: Firebase structure]

Is there a type of Firestore query that would allow me to specify which documents to search through and only return a list/array of "things" that appear in each of the said documents? If this isn't possible, what would be the best way to structure the database instead?

Comment: I think you're looking for an [array membership query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership). If that's not it, can you show a screenshot of such a document?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your response. I've added a screenshot from the Firestore Emulator. I don't think array membership query is what I was looking for exactly. My query is basically: "return the list of ID's that appear in both filterA and filterB" which would theoretically yield ["thing2"].

Comment: That is indeed quite different. It should be a matter of loading both documents and comparing the fields in them. There isn't a lot Firestore can do to help there. Did you already try reading both documents, and comparing the field values in your application code?